# Passing parameters from a windows service to a console application

Tags: c#, windows, service, console

I have a windows service that initiates a console app process and calls it at a set time.

I believe I can use the Arguments property to pass a parameter to the called console app as such... `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "0";`

Where do I get this parameter within the console app ?

Main presumably gets passed this parameter in the string array...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {                 
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Then in my Form1 class is it EventArgs e that contains this parameter?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass dataprocess = new MyClass();
        dataprocess.InsertData(dataprocess.RetrieveData(my parameter to go here));
    }
```

thanks for any help....

Comment: They are not in the forms eventargs, instead simply query: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`  -  Why are you calling a GUI app from a service?

Comment: there is no gui element as such, no client interaction it is simply running a process